# error: replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Tags: r, replace, runtime-error

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  setwd("c:/users/hp1/desktop")
  files_full <- list.files(directory,full.names = TRUE)
  cr <- data.frame()
  j = 1
  for(i in 1:332)
  {
    y <- read.csv(files_full[i])
    z <- y[complete.cases(y),]

    if (nrow(z) > threshold){
      cr[j] <- cor(z[,'sulfate'], z[,'nitrate'], method = "pearson")

      j = j+1
      }


    }
  cr

  }
```

it's showing the following error:
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, j, value = -0.222552560758546) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0 
I was expecting as j increments, values would get added to the cr dtaframe. however that is not happening.
please suggest necessary changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. If you provide a reproducible example I can show you how to clean the result. `sapply` will try to simplify the result, but you can stop it by specifying `simplify = FALSE` and remove unwanted list elements.

```
setwd("c:/users/hp1/desktop") # I would use this outside a function

corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)

  sapply(files_full, FUN = function(x) {
    y <- read.csv(x)
    z <- y[complete.cases(y),]

    if (nrow(z) > threshold){
      out <- cor(z[,'sulfate'], z[,'nitrate'], method = "pearson")
    } else {
      return(NA) # or some other way you want to handle the result
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you tell me what went wrong in my code? and also where will all the correlations be stored?

Comment: @ShivamMunshi once you run the function `myresult <- corr(...)`, the result will be in `myresult`.

Comment: dont you think 'out' will get rewritten after every loop?

Comment: i ran your code with        > cr <- corr("specdata",400)
> head(cr)              this did not produce the expected output

Comment: @ShivamMunshi you will probably have to adapt the output. If you provide a reproducible example and show what the desired output should look like, I'll be more than happy to help out.

Comment: the else statement is giving out a NULL when the if statement isnt satisfied. In the output, we donot want anything is the IF statement is not satisfied    $`specdata/001.csv`
NULL

$`specdata/002.csv`
[1] -0.01895754

$`specdata/003.csv`
NULL

$`specdata/004.csv`
[1] -0.04389737

$`specdata/005.csv`
[1] -0.06815956

$`specdata/006.csv`
NULL
is the output I'm getting and the expected output is       
## [1] -0.01896 -0.14051 -0.04390 -0.06816 -0.12351 -0.07589
thanks

Comment: @ShivamMunshi please edit your question that includes some simulated data. I suggest you have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some tips on how to do that.